# How to observe multiple states in a handlebar template from an ember controller or component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember and am struggeling with the typical "how would one do that"-Problem. What I've got is fairly simple and I know how to do it, but my way is so complicated that I do not think it's correct.

The case:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{link-to top-level}}</li>
  <li>{{link-to another-top-level</li>
  <ul class="submenu">
     <li>{{link-to submenu</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

What should happen is:

- When a route is clicked, the corresponding list element should become active.
- When a submenu is clicked the corresponding upper ul-element should get the class open

It's a fairly simple case with jQuery, but I understand that this is not scalable and abstracted and stuff.

Therefore I started with this approach:

- Create a controller / template construct for the entire navigation to handle it's state (there are some other things I need to check as well, so it came in handy).
- since ember adds the *active* class to the anchor tag I created a component to observe that:

Like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function() {
      return this.get('childViews').anyBy('active');
  }.property('childViews.@each.active') 
});
```

Replacing the *li* elements with *{{linked-list}}* does indeed work.

But what next? Do I need to add another component to watch the component to watch the build in behaviour of *active* links? Do I have to write dedicated MVC-Classes for all the DOM Elements?

There has to be a simpler way, I think. I already created a whole lotta files for such a simple behaviour that I'm thinking I'm totally on the wrong track.

My gut feeling is: That is view logic and the view should just observe a few states in the template and that's it.

What's the leanest approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question right, but why you want to add the class `open` to the corresponding upper element? It automatically get active assigned. And with correct CSS it should work as expected.

I have created a small example demonstrating what I mean. Please have a look and let me know, if that's the solution for you or what's your problem with this solution.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wifusosadega/7/edit

**EDIT**

Here is a Bootstrap flavored version: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wifusosadega/9/edit .

Comment: My main thing was, that i wanted everything in one component and not within multiple files - adn that i have additional jquery staff (such as slideToggle), that I want to attach. 

However, your solution looks much cleaner. I'll try to adapt that.